# Wordpress wp_actionscheduler_logs Много весит

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Эта таблица весит 65мб. При экспорте внутри возникает ошибка и экспортит не всю базу, можно ли её удалить? Я гуглил, вроде она не нужна, но нигде не написано, можно ли удалить? Т.к. сайт делал не я, я не знаю, что там было и вообще, как можно так загадить базу.
Можно ли её удалить или очистить? Соответственно, бекап сделать не могу, по причине, описанной в начале. Хост странный и бекап БД не дает загрузить, боюсь, что и не восстановит

Comment: Эту таблицу использует WooCommerce, ну и собственно, название таблицы говорит само за себя. Если мне не изменяет память, эта таблица очищается раз в 30 дней. Саму таблицу удалять не стоит, но при необходимости Вы ее можете очистить используя SQL запрос `TRUNCATE wp_actionscheduler_logs`, так же используя фильтр [action_scheduler_retention_period](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/action_scheduler_retention_period) можно изменить периодичность очистки этой таблицы.

Comment: @Simon Спасибо. Сделал, 98% памяти ушло, все работает и экспортируется. Еще раз спасибо!